# Simplify a logical statement

Tags: logic

I need to simplify the following statement:

[image]

According to the given answer, this is a tautology, which can be simplified to p or not p. I couldn't get there. I have started by replacing all (a -> b) by not a or b. Then I have applied De Morgan's rule twice. I think that my final result is a tautology, but it ain't p or not p. Can you please assist ? Thank you.

Comment: The LH-conjunct is : $\lnot [(p \land \lnot q) \land (q \land p)] \equiv \lnot [p \land (q \land \lnot q)] \equiv \lnot [p \land F] \equiv \lnot F \equiv T$.

Comment: The RH-conjunct is : $[p \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot q)] \equiv (p \land \lnot q)$.

Comment: We can't assist properly without even knowing what your final answer is...